# Select in nested jsonb - postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I had a hard time finding the values on a basis, as all the examples cite the same way of finding information in simple jsons.

But a friend from work gave me a solution and I came to share.

the initial question was: How to make a select in a nested json ???

A json like this:

```
{
   "vehicle":[
      {
         "vehicle_type":"Truck",
         "car_make":"Lotus",
         "car_model":"Esprit",
         "quantity":7,
         "seats":7,
         "price_hour":16,
         "price_day":147,
         "color":[
            "Purple",
            "Pink",
            "Blue",
            "White"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

To view the structure, you can use the https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: In addition to showing the desired result, please also post your postgres version.  PG12 introduces `jsonpath` capabilities.

Comment: What exactly is the *question*? This isn't a meaningful question: `How to make a select in a nested json ???`

Comment: I want make queries in the inner elements of json
And I am using pgsql 9.6

Comment: And Erwin: I don't know another way to question this... I just need to make a SELECT querie in a json as the example...

Answer (score 0):

The answer I bring uses select with regex:

```
select * from example
where example.jsonTest->>'vehicle' ~ 'color"\s*:\s*"?.*?Blue.*"?';
```

and

```
select * from example
where example.jsonTest->>'vehicle' ~ 'vehicle_type"\s*:\s*"?.*?SUV.*"?';
```

To be clear I left a working example in https://rextester.com/BQZP48785

** sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the **vehicle** with **color blue**, and **vehicle type** with **SUV**, `jsonb_array_elements()` function might be used to unnest the main array, and then putting `(j.elm->>'vehicle_type') = 'SUV'` into the `WHERE` clause would be enough for the second, while `(j.elm->>'color')::jsonb ? 'Blue'` should be used containing **jsonb** conversion with **?** operator for the first one, since `(j.elm->>'color')` extracts an array, while `(j.elm->>'vehicle_type')` does simple string pieces.

Therefore a regular expression is not needed such as below queries :

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM example e
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsonTest->'vehicle') j(elm)
 WHERE (j.elm->>'color')::jsonb ? 'Blue'
```

and

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM example e
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsonTest->'vehicle') j(elm)
 WHERE (j.elm->>'vehicle_type') = 'SUV'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1705e3fcfd8a79b132dbe88d72629000)</kbd>